# Swig defines SWIG_init with a hyphen in debug mode on windows, resulting in autogenerated C++ code that is invalid

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, swig

On Windows, I am using cmake, swig, and visual studio to build a python wrapper for my library.  In Release mode everything works fine.  In Debug, the generated code contains this line:

```
#define SWIG_init PyInit__myproject-gd
```

So Debug appends the `-gd` which is not there in Release.  The build goes on to use that symbol as a function name, which is not valid C++ because a hyphen is not allowed in an identifier.  And so this line...

```
SWIG_init(void) {
```

...causes the build to fail with this error message:

```
C:\xxx\myprojectPYTHON_wrap.cxx(807935,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '-'
C:\xxx\myprojectPYTHON_wrap.cxx(807935,1): error C2059: syntax error: '-'
C:\xxx\myprojectPYTHON_wrap.cxx(807935,17): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
C:\xxx\myprojectPYTHON_wrap.cxx(807935,17): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

How do I fix this?

**Edit**:

In release, the swig command emitted by cmake includes:

```
-interface _myproject
```

For debug it says:

```
-interface _myproject-gd
```

So in the c++ code autogenerated by swig I get a function called `_myproject` in release but `_myproject-gd` in debug.

In this file:

```
C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.26\Modules\UseSWIG.cmake
```

I see:

```
# This makes sure that the name used in the proxy code
# matches the library name created by CMake
list (APPEND SWIG_MODULE_${name}_EXTRA_FLAGS "-interface" "$<TARGET_FILE_PREFIX:${target_name}>$<TARGET_FILE_BASE_NAME:${target_name}>")
```

I have debugged that cmake generator expression and of course it evaluates to `_myproject` in release and `_myproject-gd` in debug.

In this file:

```
C:\repos\myproject\cmake\commonSettings.cmake
```

I see:

```
    if("${MSVC_RUNTIME}" STREQUAL "static")
        set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "gd")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "-gd")
    endif()
```

Removing that hyphen fixes the compile error but breaks other things.  I'm not certain, but it seems to me that the cmake configuration for swig is misappropriating a cmake variable that is intended to be used in a file (lib) name and is instead incorporating it into the name of a C++ function.  So you add a hyphen to that cmake variable, thinking that your lib name will contain a hyphen, and then your autogenerated swig code breaks.  I might be wrong, I am still digging.

**Edit #2**:

I notice that UseSWIG.cmake only sets the `-interface` flag if it has not already been set.  So, before calling `swig_add_library`, if I do something like this...

```
list (APPEND SWIG_MODULE_myproject_EXTRA_FLAGS "-interface" _myproject)
```

...it appears to fix the problem.  I can't yet be sure because my build still fails later with what appears to be a separate, unrelated problem.

Comment: One way would be to `#undef` that symbol after including that file and then `#define` it to what it should really be.  You should also contact the library maintainers.

Comment: I do not #include that file.  The #define and its usage both appear in the same .cxx file, which is autogenerated.  I would not know which library maintainer to contact as I'm not yet sure what the root cause is.  It could be that cmake is configured wrong such that it invokes swig incorrectly.  I suspect that the root cause is a mistake of mine somewhere.

Comment: If you suspect your code is at fault then we'll need a [mre]

Comment: I will try.  This is a small slice of a big project and there are a lot of moving parts.

Comment: I think somewhere in your configuration you have a `–gd` switch that’s missing a space in front of it

Comment: Almost.  It seems that the problem is not a missing space, but rather the hyphen, which gets added to a C++ function name, resulting in invalid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our site sometimes populates CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX with a value containing a hyphen e.g. "-gd".  Function swig_add_library() (defined in module UseSWIG.cmake) misappropriates this variable in two ways:

1. It uses the variable as part of the name of a function in the autogenerated C source code.  The hyphen results in invalid C.
2. It uses the variable as part of the package name and a hyphen results in the package not getting loaded at runtime.

The workaround for us was to unset CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX before calling swig_add_library() and restore CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX after (because it is required by subsequent calls to target_link_libraries):

```
set(TEMP_CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX ${CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX})
unset(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX)
swig_add_library(myproject TYPE MODULE LANGUAGE python SOURCES myproject.i)
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX ${TEMP_CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX})
```

Comment: I usually, use the `-DSWIG_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_NO_DEBUG` and  ` string(REPLACE "_d" "" Python3_LIBRARIES "${Python3_LIBRARIES}")` and use release version of the python runtime for both debug and release. The python C interface is an ABI

Comment: Oh, wow!  I see that you have been down the same deep rabbit hole as me.  Your solution looks more elegant and I will give it a try.  I am currently #defining `SWIG_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_NO_DEBUG` in a .i file and your way looks better.  I too find that I need to link the release version of the python libs, even in my debug build, and I accomplish this by telling the build only the path to the python lib, not the lib name - then it seems to look for the release version of the lib even in debug.